# Change border-color of select option box

Tags: css, electron

I am trying to change the border color of the options box for a native selects. I only need to support chrome (electron app) so no worries for backwards compability. In the attached image below you can see the orange border. That's the color I want to change.

Cheers!

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrap a div around the select html tag and set the border color of that div.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid orange;">
 <select>
  ....
 </select>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9r926pxs/1/